# tabbarview content goes below without having enough elements

Tags: flutter

`tabbarview` content scrolls below `sliverappbar` and `sliverPersistentHeader` even though there are not enough elements to be scrolled.
Await for possible answers, I need this format in `headerSliverBuilder`, `sliverappbar`, then `sliverlist` and finally `SliverPersistenHeader`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MainCollapsingToolbar extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainCollapsingToolbarState createState() => _MainCollapsingToolbarState();
}

class _MainCollapsingToolbarState extends State<MainCollapsingToolbar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: DefaultTabController(
        length: 2,
        child: NestedScrollView(
          headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
            return <Widget>[
              SliverOverlapAbsorber(
                handle: NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(context),
                sliver: SliverAppBar(
                  expandedHeight: 200.0,
                  floating: false,
                  pinned: true,
                  flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                      centerTitle: true,
                      title: Text("Collapsing Toolbar",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: 16.0,
                          )),
                      background: Image.network(
                        "https://images.pexels.com/photos/396547/pexels-photo-396547.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350",
                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                      )),
                ),
              ),
              SliverList(
                delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        NameLevelInformation(user: user),
                        Row(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                          children: [
                            InformativeColumn(
                              num: user.destinos.length, 
                              label: 'Destinos', 
                              redirectScreen: DestinosCompletosScreen(user: user,),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              height: 20, 
                              width: 1, 
                              color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                            ),
                            InformativeColumn(
                              num: user.followers.length, 
                              label: 'Seguidores', 
                              redirectScreen: FollowScreen(user: user,),
                            ),
                            Container(
                              height: 20, 
                              width: 1, 
                              color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5),
                            ),
                            InformativeColumn(
                              num: user.scores['global'], 
                              label: 'Experiencia',
                              redirectScreen: null,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        PerfilProgressContainer(user: user, places: places,),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ]),
              ),
              SliverPersistentHeader(
                delegate: _SliverAppBarDelegate(
                  TabBar(
                    labelColor: Colors.black87,
                    unselectedLabelColor: Colors.grey,
                    tabs: [
                      Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.info), text: "Tab 1"),
                      Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.lightbulb_outline), text: "Tab 2"),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                pinned: true,
              ),
            ];
          },
          body: TabBarView(
             children: const [
               PerfilTabPost(),
               PerfilTabPost2(),
               PerfilTabPost3(),
             ]
           ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _SliverAppBarDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  _SliverAppBarDelegate(this._tabBar);

  final TabBar _tabBar;

  @override
  double get minExtent => _tabBar.preferredSize.height;
  @override
  double get maxExtent => _tabBar.preferredSize.height;

  @override
  Widget build(
      BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    return new Container(
      child: _tabBar,
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(_SliverAppBarDelegate oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

I have tried to use `SliverOverlapAbsorber` but it only allows it in the `SliverAppBar`, but not `SliverPersistenHeader`, that is why it does not work correctly when I use the `SliverOverlapInjector` in `PerfilTabPost()` for example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PerfilTabPost extends StatelessWidget {
  const PerfilTabPost({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomScrollView(
      slivers: [
        SliverOverlapInjector(
          handle: NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(context),
        ),
        Consumer<PostProvider>(
          builder: (context, postProvider, _) {
            var posts = postProvider.posts;
            
            return SliverGrid(
              gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 3,
                crossAxisSpacing: 1.0,
                mainAxisSpacing: 1.0,
                mainAxisExtent: 150,
              ),
              delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                (context, index) {
                  if (posts.isEmpty) {
                    return const Center(
                      child: Text(
                        'Aún no hay publicaciones',
                        style: MyStyles.primaryStyle,
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                  var post = posts[index];
                  return InkWell(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => PerfilTabPostDetails(posts: posts, initialIndex: index)));
                    },
                    child: Stack(
                      children: [
                        Positioned.fill(
                          child: Image(
                            image: CachedNetworkImageProvider(post['postUrl']),
                            fit: BoxFit.fill,
                          )
                        ),
                        Positioned(
                          bottom: 5,
                          right: 5,
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                            children: [
                              const Icon(
                                Icons.favorite, 
                                size: 14, 
                                color: secondaryColor, 
                                shadows: [
                                  Shadow(
                                    color: primaryColor,
                                    offset: Offset(2, 2),
                                    blurRadius: 5,
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(width: 5,),
                              Text(
                                post['likes'].length.toString(),
                                style: MyStyles.secondaryStyle.copyWith(
                                  shadows: [
                                    const Shadow(
                                      color: primaryColor,
                                      offset: Offset(2, 2),
                                      blurRadius: 5,
                                    )
                                  ]
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          )
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  );
                },
                childCount: posts.length,
              ),
            );
          }
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```